# update-database -force command is not updating the base in entity framework code -first

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

May be this question seems duplicate. But here are the issue that I am facing with the command.

If I run this command,

```
update-database -force
```

the first error I gets..

> There is already an object named tblAbc in the database

Then I googled and everytime I get a stackoverflow link for suggesting to run 
  **Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges**

If I run this command and then run the update command, No error - Running seed method

> But it doesn't sync the database with the new updates

Then I tried for number of times but same issue, hence I looked for some alternate solution & I got.

to use update-database -Script but if I run this command and get the following error.

> User canceld Save dialog box

Then I tried to fix this by opening SQL Managment Studio and

> Tools>>Options>>designers>> unchecked the Prevent saving changes that required table recreation

But after this also same error message.

Then I tried to add the following coniguration in my context class

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion  <context, Configuration>());
```

It ran with success and Running Seed method but it doesn't sync the latest updates.

Comment: Are you using EF with an existing database?

Comment: @heymega..
yes..I have an existing database that is generated using ef code-first now I made some changes in my db(C#) and needs to update the same in sql tables

Comment: It could be a genuine message that you have defined two database tables with the same name.  I've done this many times before.  It might be worth going through each one and checking the names that have been specified if you have them set up with fluent API.  Check your `ToTable()` values for duplicates

Comment: @Coulton..actually suppose I delete the tblAbc and then runs the command then it gives me same error but instead of tblAbc it gives tblXyz

Comment: @Coulton..See if I have C# class class as Abc using fluent API I set the table name as tblAbc..

Comment: Ok, so have you checked for the next one to see if that is a duplicate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Using an Existing Database**

Depending on the state of your context you need to the one of the following...

**IF YOUR DATABASE CONTEXT CONTAINS ONLY YOUR EXISTING TABLES AND NO CUSTOM CHANGES DO THE FOLLOWING**

```
Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges
```

This will create a blank migration script

```
update-database
```

This will update the database to this migration but no changes will be applied. You can now add your changes to the database context. After you have finished do the following

```
Add-Migration Custom
```

This will generate a migration script with your changes in it. Then update your database again.

```
update-database
```

**IF YOUR DATABASE CONTEXT CONTAINS YOUR EXISTING TABLES AND ALSO YOUR CUSTOM CHANGES**

```
Add-migration Initial
```

This generates a migration script. Go through the migration script and remove any references to existing tables in both the UP and DOWN methods. You will be left with a script which only includes your custom logic.

```
update-database
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Update the migration file with the type, size and maxLength.

Example:
maxLength: 50,
type: "varchar(50)",

Properties:

[image: Properties]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30900648)