# .net core EntityFramework "Add-Migration" not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

After I deleted the Database in (localdb)\MSSqlLocalDB and Contents of the Migrations folder in my .NET Core MVC Project, I expected it to create a new Migration and lets me create the Database with "Add-Migration Init" and "Update-Dabase". However it won't create the Migration due to not finding the Database (Error Code: 4060).
I don't understand how I can create the Database from PMC when it says that. And I don't understand why it tells me that.

Comment: have you runed: Enable-Migrations.
Check step by step this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/sql-server-migration-assistant?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: "Enable-Migrations is obsolete" says PMC

Comment: you'll need to use the ['dotnet' command line variation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/).

Comment: the dotnet command version of "add-migration" tells me the same

Comment: After creating my Database with SSMA I now receive Error 208, because it obviously finds none of the tables it should create.

Comment: Perhaps try `update-database -force` or look here might be something useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517933/update-database-force-command-is-not-updating-the-base-in-entity-framework-code

Comment: It tells me that none of these parameters exists. The Thread is probably referring to an older version. I looked it up and there were no such parameters (nor similar) documented unfortunatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean up your project and re-build it. What also work by me is to close and restart visual studio.